# Looping through the pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement the looping through the pictures with HTML, CSS, Jquery/Javascript in this way:
[image]
There are few pictures (all are visible and don't move) on one page and want to loop through each of them (one at a time) and pop-up some text above current image. If I hover over Picture C, for example, the looping should stop and when unhover - should continue from Picture C and so on. But I am not sure how to implement this. Could anyone advise me what should I use or similar examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I did for you, hope it is what you are looking for. (Images I used for testing were 200px per 200px.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Page title</title>


   <script src=http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js></script>
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var currentImg = 1,
                totalImages = 4
                loopTime = 1000,
                intervalId = null;


            function displayTitle(imgNbr) {
                $('.title').hide();
                $('#image'+imgNbr).prev('div').show();
            }

            $('img').on('mouseover', function() {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                displayTitle($(this).parent().attr('id').substring(5));
            }).on('mouseout', function() {
                currentImg = $(this).parent().attr('id').substring(5);
                startLoop();
            })

            function startLoop() {
                intervalId = setInterval(function() {
                    displayTitle(currentImg);
                    currentImg = ((currentImg == totalImages) ? 1 : parseInt(currentImg)+1);
                }, loopTime);
            }
            startLoop();
        });
   </script>
   <style>
       .imgcontainer {
           margin: 10px;
           float: left;
           position: relative;
           text-align: center;
       }
       .title {
           position: absolute;
           top: 70px;
           left: 60px;
           color: #ffffff;
           display: none;
       }
       .img {
           clear: both;
       }
   </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="title">title 1</div>
    <div class="img" id="image1"><img src="images/image1.jpg" /></div>
</div>

<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="title">title 2</div>
    <div class="img" id="image2"><img src="images/image2.jpg" /></div>
</div>    

<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="title">title 3</div>
    <div class="img" id="image3"><img src="images/image3.jpg" /></div>
</div>

<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="title">title 4</div>
    <div class="img" id="image4"><img src="images/image4.jpg" /></div>
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a "Carousel".

If you can use JQuery, than [CarouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/) is a very good option, [here](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/continuously-scrolling.php) is the example.

And if you want to rely on JavaScript, you can use [Conveyor Belt Slideshow Script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/leftrightslide.htm).

Comment: It's not exactly what I neeed. The pictures must not move.

Comment: @user1047517 you've edited later these words "_and don't move_", how do I predict them earlier?

Comment: Before editing I have written a comment to you and waited for a while but you didn't respond. Now you are trying to argue.

Comment: Well i am sorry if you feel so, but i did not mean to argue, its just a problem of our native time difference.. :)

Answer (score 0):

As @Asif says in his answer, there are many publicly available JavaScript components for this type of thing.

I have used [Lightbox Image Viewer v2.03a](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/lightbox2/index.htm) from [Dynamic Drive](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/) several times (which is not quite what you're after), but there are plenty more to have a look at on that site, one of which might have exactly what you're after.